# Image validation on Client side

Tags: jquery, image

Is it possible to validate the image dimension on client  side using jquery or any other framework?

Answer (score -1):

```
$.validator.addMethod("imageonly", function(value,element){     
        var pathLength = value.length;
        var lastDot = value.lastIndexOf(".");
        var fileType = value.substring(lastDot,pathLength).toLowerCase();
        return this.optional(element) ||  fileType.match(/(?:.gif|.jpg|.png|.bmp)$/);
    }, "Please upload image file only");
```